# What does this VHDL code do?

Tags: vhdl

I am working on a project but whatever I do I can’t understand what this code does. Since I am not familiar with VHDL, it’s really hard for me to understand the purpose of this code.

```
library iee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use work.my_package.all;

Entity multiplier is

    generic (size: integer :=4);
    Port (a,b : in unsigned( size-1 downto 0);
        y : out unsigned( size-1 downto 0));

End multiplier ;

ARCHITECTURE behavior of multiplier is

Begin

    y<= mult(a,b);

End behavior;
```

Comment: You also have a package use work.my_package.all; y<= mult(a,b) I think **mult(a,b)** is a function in the package..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an **entity** which describes **the interface of your design**. In this case inputs `a` and `b` as well as output `y`. These are all 4-bit values.

The **architecture** contains **the implementation** of what you're trying to do (the body if you will). In this case it's simply a multiplication of `a` and `b`, which is assigned to `y`. And (should you be confused) no, the `<=` does not stand for "smaller than or equal to" but it's an assignment.

Answer (score 3):

It takes two 4 bit inputs and produces a 4 bit product on the output. This is a little weird as the input size is equal to the output so if you multiply together 2 big numbers you get an overflow.

Answer (score 1):

just look for the ARCHITECTURE section and you can see that you do multiplying of two integers a and b which are defined in the Entity section.
the ARCHITECTURE section always describes how you system behaves!